# How to handle a Core Data "can not fulfill fault" error

Tags: core-data

Everything is cruisin' along just fine in an Entity (A) with a Relationship to another Entity (B). Then some of the related data (B) gets corrupted, and A can not fulfill a fault because the related thing in B is no longer available.

I would be happy just cleaning out any A records that have this problem, but don't know how to detect if the relationship is broken without the program actually throwing the error (and bombing).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why code a workaround for some other bug in your program? The case you describe should be solved on the level of the "corruption", not the consequences.

In other words, you should look at your code and prevent that "*some of the related data (B) gets corrupted*". If you have invalid `Bs`, simply delete them. If your model is set up correctly, it should automatically sever the relationship with `A`.